# django - Mulitple excludes in template filter

Tags: python, django

I have a custom template tag for filtering. The `get_files_by_type` works perfectly, but now i want to do an "exclude type" tag too. However, I don't know how to format this one, as the exclude may be 1 or more tags.

How would I do this in the function and how do I need to format the template? i.e would the template be?

```
{% exclude_files_by_type Site.sitefiles_set.all 'Site Plan,'Cabinet Photo' as files %}
```

extras.py

```
    from django import template
    from networks.models import SiteFiles

    register = template.Library()

    @register.assignment_tag
    def get_files_by_type(SiteFiles, type):
        return SiteFiles.filter(file_type__type=type)

    def exclude_files_by_type(SiteFiles, type):

    return SiteFiles.exclude
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
{% exclude_files_by_type Site.sitefiles_set.all "Site Plan, Cabinet Photo" as files %}
```

and your assignment tag:

```
@register.assignment_tag
def exclude_files_by_type(SiteFiles, types):
    type_list = [type.strip() for type in types.split(',')]
    return SiteFiles.exclude(file_type__type__in=type_list)
```

To add more types to the exclusion query you should place them in the argument separated by commas:

```
{% exclude_files_by_type Site.sitefiles_set.all "Site Plan, Cabinet Photo, Last Summer, Group Selfies" as files %}
```